# vps, ram, Python

Tags: python, vps, ram

Есть бот на питоне, который парсит сайт в поисках товаров. В целях ускорения, уже проверенные товары помещались в словарь товаров, которые не нужно проверять. Отсюда появилась проблема с ОЗУ. Тогда я добавил полную чистку словаря и график стал выглядеть вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, учитывая, что список становился пустым, места должно было освобождаться больше, но такого не происходило. Тогда я решил перейти на sqlite, но он не позволяет нескольким потокам разом искать нужные данные, а идея создавать новую ДБ для каждого потока меня не радовала.

Тогда я решил реализовать все через txt файл и Numpy для ускорения

```
db = [item1, item2, item3]
file = open('bandb.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
ar = [line for line in file.readlines()]
bansarr = numpy.array([ar])
for i in db:
    if len(numpy.where(bansarr==f'{i}')[1]) > 0:
        bans.append(i)
```

В течение около 8 часов шло идеально, но после потребление ОЗУ резко выросло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]и при повторном запуске сразу улетало в края.

Отказавшись от Numpy, ОЗУ все равно слишком быстро ползет наверх. Я бы и продолжил пользоваться  самым первым вариантом, но в следующем проекте кол-во товаров вырастет в разы и никаких ресурсов тут не хватит. Пользуюсь vps от бегета, с 3 ядрами, 3гб ОЗУ и 10 нвме. Изначально этого хватало, но в попытке оптимизации, чувствуется, что не хватит абсолютно никаких ресурсов.

Пользоваться Mysql или postgres не хочу. Мне бы локальную БД, как sqlite.
Вопросы следующие: Как правильно оптимизировать и чистить код? Может, проблема в бегете? Как в итоге можно организовать БД, с максимальной скоростью и стабильным потреблением ресурсов?

```
cleartime = datetime.datetime.now()
ban = {}

def clear():
    global ban
    global cleartime
    minustime = datetime.datetime.now() - cleartime
    if minustime > datetime.timedelta(minutes=50):
        hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour + 3
        minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
        if hour > 10 and minute < 50:
            ban.clear()
            cleartime = datetime.datetime.now()


def checkitems(db):
    for item in db['data']:
        id = item['id']
        try:
            if ban[id]:
                continue
        except:
            pass
        # Высчитывает, выгодный ли товар
        ban[id] = True


while True:
    try:
        clear()

        req = requests.post('https://site.com').json()
        if req:
            loop = checkitems(req)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Сформулируйте чётко - что именно вы храните, в каком формате, возможны ли повторения данных и т.д. Вам нужно чётко понять ваши данные сначала и что с ними алгоритмически оптимально делать, а не метаться в поисках "золотой пули", просто рандомно применяя вроде как быстрые инструменты совершенно неправильным образом. Чётко опишите ваши данные и задачу, прямо в вопросе. Тогда можно будет подобрать правильный алгоритм работы, а потом уже можно будет выбирать подходящие инструменты.

Comment: В частности `Numpy` хорош для работы с числами фиксированного размера, но вы храните в нём питоновские объекты (строки), а не числа. И ищете вы в `numpy.array` совершенно не оптимально. Тут вообще скорее обычный питоновский `set` больше бы подошёл со скоростью проверки на вхождение `O(1)`.

Comment: Я храню id товара в виде строки: '82abls2342'(например). Повторения одного и того же id в файле возможно, но их процент ничтожен.

Comment: Ну вот тут подошёл бы `set`, но опять же если ОЗУ хватит на хранение всех `id`. И в куске кода, который вы привели, у вас тройное использование ОЗУ как минимум: сначала `readlines()` читает весь файл в список, потом вы делаете из этого списка ещё один список с помощью спискового сокращения, а потом ещё и `numpy.array` из этого списка делаете. То есть у вас три копии файла в ОЗУ в этот момент получается.

Comment: А если ОЗУ не хватит? Все-таки следующий проект требовательнее, а бесконечно повышать ОЗУ не получится. Мог бы чистить всю дб, ибо некоторые товары становятся не актуальны, но сильно это не помогает. Видимо, код хранит что-то даже после удаления данных.

Comment: Ну вот надо разбираться, как вы храните, как вы удаляете

Comment: Вот тут то и проблемы. Как хранить, пытаюсь тут узнать. До этого был словарь, который чистил путем dict.clear()

Comment: Ну вы же код не показали, как вы это делаете. Если он написан так же, как тот код, который вы привели, то там возможно что угодно.

Comment: Не смог добавить код в комментарий, поэтому закинул в ответ. Вот так все и происходит, остальная часть просто считает выгоду и отправляет в телеграм(не взаимодействует с этим словарем).

Comment: Для начала попробуйте никогда не использовать `clear()`. Да, он очищает хранилище объекта, но память объекта при этом не освобождается, она остаётся как бы занятой "про запас". Лучше каждый раз создавайте новый объект, тогда старый объект сможет очиститься, то есть для очистки делайте `ban = {}`.